# Element with multiple list items gets pushed higher than elements with single list item

Tags: html, css

I want to list players and their bets in a roulette game. When the number of `<li>` tags in the `<ul>` is different, the position of the `<r-players>` element change:

[image: photo]

but when there are equal numbers of tags, it looks fine:

[image: photo]

Why is this happening?

Here is my HTML:

```
<r-panel>
    <r-players>
    <r-button>Blue</r-button>
    <ul>
        <li><span><ion-icon name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon> 200 </span> aaa</li>
        <li><span><ion-icon name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon> 200 </span> aaa</li>
        <li><span><ion-icon name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon> 200 </span> aaa</li>
    </ul>
    </r-players>

    <r-players>
    <r-button>Yellow</r-button>
    <ul>
        <li><span><ion-icon name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon> 200 </span> aaa</li>
    </ul>
    </r-players>

    <r-players>
    <r-button>Purple</r-button>
    <ul>
        <li><span><ion-icon name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon> 200 </span> aaa</li>
    </ul>
    </r-players>
</r-panel>
```

and my CSS:

```
r-players{
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    width:calc((100% / 3) - 5px);
    height:calc(100%);
}
r-players li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family:'Quicksand';
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
}
r-players li span
{
    font-size:13px;
    background-color:#333;
    border-radius:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    color:#ddd;

}
r-button{

}
r-players li span ion-icon
{
    margin-bottom:-2px;
}
r-panel
{
    position:relative;
    width:750px;
    height:calc(100% - 300px);
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 25px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:20px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid HTML, so you'll want to tag for your other software or reduce your example to use standard HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` on `r-players`

```
.r-players{
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    vertical-align:top;/*Add this */
    display:inline-block;
    width:calc((100% / 3) - 5px);
    height:calc(100%);
}
```